# Check variable and update database after threads are finished

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

this is my first question in stackoverflow.

I have something like this:

```
@Async("myExecutor")
void updateUsers() {
        AtomicInteger errorCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
        Pageable pageRequest = Pageable.ofSize(100);
        Page<User> page = new PageImpl<>(Collections.emptyList());
        do {
            try {
                page = userRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
                page.forEach(this::update);
                pageRequest = pageRequest.next();
            } catch (MyCustomException e) {
                String errorMessage = "Error updating user. " + e.getMessage();
                log.error(errorMessage);
                errorCounter.incrementAndGet();
            }
        } while (!page.isLast());
}
```

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor myExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(25);

    return executor;
}
```

I need to know the value of my 'errorCounter' to update my db or not when the process is finished, so is a must do something when all threads are finished and the counter value. I found something about CountDownLatch or implement ExecutorService without @Async("myExecutor"), just instance at the class the ExecutorService and use awaitTermination.

Is my first time working with Threads so I dont have a lot of experience with that.

Thanks and sorry for my English (=

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CompletableFuture` for that.

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    // Some time consuming computation
    return "Result";
}).thenAccept(result -> {
    // This will be executed when the computation is done.
    System.out.println(result);
});
```

`supplyAsync` starts a task in a separate thread that does some computation and returns a result.
`thenAccept` is a callback that is called when the computation is finished, with the result of the computation as a parameter.

You can combine `@Async` with `CompletableFuture`:

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> asyncMethod() {
    // Some time consuming task
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("Result");
}

public void callerMethod() {
    asyncMethod().thenAccept(result -> {
        // This will be executed when asyncMethod is done.
        System.out.println(result);
    });
}
```

When you call `callerMethod()`, it will call `asyncMethod()`, which will be executed in a separate thread. The `thenAccept` callback will be called when `asyncMethod()` is finished, with the result of `asyncMethod()` as a parameter.

In your case, you can use a `CompletableFuture` that wraps the execution of your tasks and retrieves the value of the error counter when all tasks have finished. This can be achieved by using the `thenApply` or `thenAccept` methods of the `CompletableFuture`.